# find which executable uses a particular library in debian

Tags: debian

I want to update a particular library (libarchive13) from debian repo but prior doing so i would like to find out which executables are using this library. Is there any way to find this information?

Answer (score 0):

In order to view which executable uses a particular library you can execute the command:

> $lsof -n|grep library_name

This will list all open files including any libraries currently used and the equivalent executable responsible for opening the file (in other words the program using the library).

The above works fine as long as the library is in use at the moment you execute the command. If your executable is not running, which in turn it means the library is not used, then the results will not contain any information for the library you are interested in.

Another way to get further information if your executable is not running, is to list the packages that depend on the specific library using the following command:

> $apt-cache rdepends --installed library_name

Since the above command will return a list of ALL the packages that depend on the library of interest, the "--installed" flag is used in order to display only the depended packages that are installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update a particular library (libarchive13) from debian repo

If this is so you know whether something needs restarting, look for `checkrestart` in the `debian-goodies` package.